# Javascript event for PC, iPad and iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, html

Is it possible for a single webpage with mouseover, drag-and-drop designed with HTML5 to work in PC, iPad and iPhone ? If not, what changes must we make ? For example, for a site like this [Sample](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/googlebox/) to work what changes must I make for iPad and iPhone ?

Comment: Wow, that's looks horrible! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, look at Peter-Paul Koch's [Touch table](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableTouch.html) for a nice summary of event support.

Comment: So I must assume there is no common method. Ok.